# ASP.NET Core 2.2 web app on Ubuntu - how to implement Data Protection

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, ubuntu-18.04

I've started using Ubuntu (18.04) to host some simple .NET Core 2.2 websites. And when the site is deployed and started I see the following:

> warn:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[59]
>          Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when
>   application exits.  warn:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
>          No XML encryptor configured. Key {c45288a6-63f8-4408-abdb-7894fb6d4e45} may be persisted to storage in
>   unencrypted form.  Hosting environment: Production  Content root path:
>   /var/www/mysite  Now listening on: http://localhost:5010  Application
>   started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.  warn:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
>          Failed to determine the https port for redirect.

So what is the best and secured way of implementing Key Storage Provider for Linux (and possibly for Windows too, universal)? Is there an existing one? Are there any examples?

PS. Yes, I've seen this docs - [Key Storage Providers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).

Answer (score 0):

The way we implemented this, supporting load balancing scenarios as well is by using Azure ATS as the key repository.

The configuration looks this way:

```
  string storageUrl = "https://[your account here].blob.core.windows.net";
  string sasToken = "?sv=20XX-XX-XX&ss=x&srt=xxx&sp=xxxx&...";
  string containerName = "data-protection-XXXX-XXXX-container";
  string blobName = "data-protection-XXXX-XXXX-blob";

   // Create the new Storage URI
   Uri storageUri = new Uri($"{storageUrl}{sasToken}");

   //Create the blob client object.
   CloudBlobClient blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(storageUri);

   //Get a reference to a container. Create it if it does not exist.
   CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

   // (NOTE: internal library, do not use in your code)
   AsyncHelper.Guarded<bool>(() => { return container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();  });


   services.AddDataProtection()
        .SetApplicationName("[your application name here]")
        .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(container, blobName)
        .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(new TimeSpan(365 * 10, 0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Note: Review the encryption options when configuring Data Protection for extra security.

Comment: well, that should do. but what about some local solution? I'm new to this kind of stuff with ubuntu, so I wanted to know how people usually do it right on that OS.

Comment: In windows you can specify a directory to keep your keys, they will be reload when the app restart, I never did on Linux, look into the configuration system available methods.